# Building a all time top-k score leaderboard

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, database-design

Suppose we are building a module for game which keeps track of the all time top scores.
Whenever players complete a game, a service will publish the player's score.

Whenever we call our service, it should return the top 5 scores (along with names) of the players.

How can I approach this?

```
I was just thinking of implement Top K algo using min heap.
But drawbacks are
1. Single host - not scalable
2. No support for streaming data, we should have the data ready
3. Not processing parallelly
```

Comment: Create a Score table with a foreign key back to the Player table.  When you want the top 5 scores, query the Score table.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc would that be a scalable solution?

Comment: Sure, depending on how many database servers you deploy.